# The problem repeated information in crawling next page and lack of information using beautiful soup and webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl the job's links from this [web](https://www.vietnamworks.com/tim-viec-lam/tat-ca-viec-lam).

At first, I will explain [my code](https://github.com/gialuong2801/abc/blob/main/demo.py): 
I will crawl all the links of each job using `for`.
After getting all the links on the first page, I will move to the next page and repeat crawling the links of the job. 
But the program returns the result like this:
[image]
As you can see, from the 11th and so on, the link is repeated as the first 10 links.
My assumption is that it doesn't actually go to the next page but still crawling data from the old page. In this case, there are how many pages, the program will crawl the 1st page with the same times.  
And there should have more than 9 links on the 1st page.
I don't really know how to fix that. 
How can I solve this problem?
Sincerely thanks!

Comment: Please avoid posting links to code, your code should be in question, formatted as such.

Comment: yes, I understand that but I am stuck in how to post the long code in the questions :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests


def main(url):
    params = {
        "x-algolia-agent": "Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser",
        "x-algolia-application-id": "JF8Q26WWUD",
        "x-algolia-api-key": "ecef10153e66bbd6d54f08ea005b60fc"
    }
    data = "{\"requests\":[{\"indexName\":\"vnw_job_v2\",\"params\":\"query=&hitsPerPage=1000&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%22*%22%2C%22-jobRequirement%22%2C%22-jobDescription%22%5D&attributesToHighlight=%5B%5D&query=&facetFilters=%5B%5D&filters=&numericFilters=%5B%5D&page=0&restrictSearchableAttributes=%5B%22jobTitle%22%2C%22skills%22%2C%22company%22%5D\"}]}"

    r = requests.post(url, params=params, data=data)
    for item in r.json()['results'][0]['hits']:
        print(item['jobTitle'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://jf8q26wwud-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries')
```

Comment: Sincerely thanks for your answer but I want to crawl the link of jobs :( not the name ones :(

Comment: @Luong the JSON response include all your desired data.